# How to Split a string by space and store in form of key value in map in Java?

Tags: java, string, split, delimiter

I have a String of consisting of parameters separated by space of the form:

```
Reference=R1,R2 GroupId=G01 Date=12/02/2017 15:25.
```

I need to split the string in such a way that left hand side of the '=' token is key and the one to the right is the value which will be stored in a map. Eg.

```
Key         Value
Reference    R1,R2
GroupId      G01
Date         12/02/2017 15.25
```

I did try splitting the string by using String.split(" ") but the date parameter has a space between date and time which will disturb the arrangement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try splitting on the following regex pattern:

```
\s+(?=[^=]+=)
```

This says to split on any amount of whitespace, which is immediately followed by a key plus `=`.  Note that this split does *not* consume anything other than the separating whitespace, turning out keys with values intact.

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
String input = "Reference=R1,R2 GroupId=G01 Date=12/02/2017 15:25";
String[] parts = input.split("\\s+(?=[^=]+=)");
for (String part : parts) {
    map.put(part.split("=")[0], part.split("=")[1]);
    System.out.println(part);
}
```

This outputs:

```
Reference=R1,R2
GroupId=G01
Date=12/02/2017 15:25
```

The only extra step I did not explicitly test here is generation of the map with its keys and values.

Comment: Yes its Java. Works perfectly! Thanks!!

Comment: if we have trailing and leading spaces before or after '=' or if there are spaces between R1 and R2 or G01 G02 how can the regular expression be modfiied to handle the scenarios?

Comment: i did try that but that  further splits the values by spaces in between. Example if Reference="R1, R2"  (space between R1 and R2) then it would treat Reference=R1 and R2 as two different expressions instead of one. Regardless of spaces between R1 and R2 or after it should treat Reference="R1,  R2" as one

Comment: @user3628645 Please [check the demo](https://rextester.com/CHHAX60792).  Also note that what you are asking for here is _way_ too long for a bunch of comments.  Changing your question after several other users have already answered it is seriously frowned upon on this site, and you should avoid doing that.

Comment: It works fine!! Sorry for changing the question so late. Shall be more cautious next tine. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

This solution you can try

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class SplitTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str="Reference=R1,R2 GroupId=G01 Date=12/02/2017 15:25 GroupId2=G02 Date=12/02/2017 30:25 Date=12/02/2017 30:25 Date=12/02/2017 30:25 GroupId3=G03";
    String[] split = str.split(" ");
    List<String> asList = Arrays.asList(split);
    List<String> newList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < asList.size();) {
        if(asList.get(i).toString().startsWith("Date")){
            String str1 = asList.get(i);
            String str2 = asList.get(i+1);
            newList.add(str1+" "+str2);
            i=i+2;
        }else{
            newList.add(asList.get(i));
            ++i;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(newList.toArray());
}
```

}

Output

```
Reference=R1,R2
GroupId=G01 
Date=12/02/2017 15:25 
GroupId2=G02
Date=12/02/2017 30:25 
Date=12/02/2017 30:25 
Date=12/02/2017 30:25 
GroupId3=G03
```